# How do I get the current logged in user in my express application?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, scheduler, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion Scheduler in my MEAN-stack application. This is the code for handling getting / inserting / editing the appointments:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("meanstacknew");
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.post("/GetData", (req, res) => {
    var user = req.user;

    const token = req.get("authorization");
    dbo.collection('ScheduleData').find({}).toArray((err, cus) => {
        res.send(cus);
       console.log(token);
    });
});
app.post("/BatchData", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    var eventData = [];
    if (req.body.action == "insert" || (req.body.action == "batch" && req.body.added.length > 0)) {
        (req.body.action == "insert") ? eventData.push(req.body.value) : eventData = req.body.added;
        for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
            var sdate = new Date(eventData[i].StartTime);
            var edate = new Date(eventData[i].EndTime);
            eventData[i].StartTime = (new Date(+sdate - (sdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
            eventData[i].EndTime = (new Date(+edate - (edate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
            eventData[i].CreatedBy =  //here I want to send the email to the database
            dbo.collection('ScheduleData').insertOne(eventData[i]);
        }
    }
    if (req.body.action == "update" || (req.body.action == "batch" && req.body.changed.length > 0)) {
        (req.body.action == "update") ? eventData.push(req.body.value) : eventData = req.body.changed;
        for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
            delete eventData[i]._id;
            var sdate = new Date(eventData[i].StartTime);
            var edate = new Date(eventData[i].EndTime);
            eventData[i].StartTime = (new Date(+sdate - (sdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
            eventData[i].EndTime = (new Date(+edate - (edate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
            dbo.collection('ScheduleData').updateOne({ "Id": eventData[i].Id }, { $set: eventData[i] });
        }
    }
    if (req.body.action == "remove" || (req.body.action == "batch" && req.body.deleted.length > 0)) {
        (req.body.action == "remove") ? eventData.push({ Id: req.body.key }) : eventData = req.body.deleted;
        for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
            dbo.collection('ScheduleData').deleteOne({ "Id": eventData[i].Id });
        }
    }
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

I am calling those endpoints in my `schedule.component.ts`:

```
 private dataManager: DataManager = new DataManager({
url: 'http://localhost:8000/GetData',
crudUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/BatchData',
adaptor: new UrlAdaptor,
crossDomain: true
  });
```

I am using the JWT token for user authorization at the moment, for example, this is my /profile endpoint:

```
   router.get('/profile', authRequired, (req, res) => {
       User.findOne({_id: req.decoded.userId}).select('username email').exec((err, user) =>{
          if(err){
              res.json({success: false, message: err});
          } else {
              if(!user){
                  res.json({success: false, message: 'User not found'});
              } else {
                  res.json({success: true, user: user})
              }
          }
       });
    });
```

How can I access the users email to set the 'createdBy' field in the appointment?
If I console.log the token this way I just get `undefined`

This is the authRequired function in middleware.js file:

```
function authRequired(req, res, next) {
const token = req.get("authorization");
if (!token) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: "No token provided" });
} else {
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: "Token is invalid" + err });
        } else {
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
        }
         });
}
}

module.exports = {
authRequired: authRequired
};
```

Comment: Are you saying the console.log(token); in app.post("/GetData" is logging undefined?

Comment: no, console.log(token)

Comment: @Chev retrieving / setting the data works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are not running `authRequired` middleware on the `POST /GetData` route so the token is not extracted. Make sure you are also sending the token in the POST.

Update the route as you do in `router.get('/profile', authRequired, (req, res) => {` so you can get the decoded token.

```
app.post("/GetData", authRequired, (req, res) => {
    var user = req.decoded; //decoded
    ...
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that I already tried that. If I pass that middleware into that post route, the retrieving of the appointments stops working

Comment: In your code, you were doing `var user = req.user;` which will not exist and also `const token = req.get("authorization")` which would not exist. There is nothing in that answer code that would cause the `dbo.collection('ScheduleData').find()` to break. Set breakpoints on `var user = req.decoded;` and let me know what you get.

Comment: can you maybe help me out with TeamViewer regarding this issue?